# Spring profiles ambiguity

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-profiles

I have two @Component beans implementing the same interface. Has a profile annotation and the other one doesn't, like below.

```
@Component
@Profile("mock")
public class CompMock implements Comp {...}

@Component
public class CompReal implements Comp {...}
```

If I run the application with `-Dspring.profiles.active=mock`, why is the second bean wired in instead of the first one which is explicitly annotated with the Profile("mock") ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@Profile("mock")` means include, if the profile is "mock". That's all. `@Profile` does not indicate a preference.

There are several ways to solve your problem, including adding `@Profile("!mock")` to `CompReal`.

Comment: Fixed it by adding the Primary annotation on CompMock level. Thanks @zeroflagL

Comment: @Profile(!mock) solves the issue, but it looks really ugly :) would be great to have more beautiful way to fix it